# Forcing ReactJS to detect new native DOM element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, cocoon-gem

Currently using a gem to dynamically generate form elements and as a result having to render reactjs elements into the DOM through js (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

The entire react component html is generated server-side using this gem and inserted using js (instead of using ReactDOM.render) so react has no chance to detect/render this new component.

Is there a react function or event I can call to force react to detect/render the component from this native element?

Comment: A bit unclear why you would use cocoon in combination with react? Cocoon manipulates a form for submitting as a whole to the server, while react works client-side, wouldn't it be better to just use react completely?

Comment: Possibly... but ultimately wanted to avoid having to rewrite rails forms in react